# Magento 1.9 cron job not running

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Magento cron job is not running. Not sure why. I ssh'd and when I run

```
ps aufx | grep cron
```

I get

```
daniel   30112  0.0  0.0 110456  2196 pts/0    S+   16:42   0:00              
\_ grep --color=auto cron
```

To me it seems that there isn't any job running.

Comment: Did you use `crontab -e` like in [This tutorial](https://amasty.com/blog/configure-magento-cron-job/) and many others?